# Способы авторизации без использования сессий

Tags: php, javascript, сессия, авторизация

Сейчас использую сессии на сайте и постоянная проблема в том, что каждый день, когда захожу на сайт приходится заново вводить логин/пароль. Особенно это актуально для *Safari*. Как можно иначе идентифицировать пользователя, чтобы авторизаия не требовалась каждый день? Ресурс не имеет важной информации, а пользователям нужны профили только для малых функций на сайте, поэтому постоянный выход не нужен. Пытался использовать такой код, для проверки работы:

```js
storage = globalStorage['site.ru']

storage['userName'] = 'Vasya'
alert(storage['userName']);
```

Но в *Safari* получил такую ошибку:

> Can't find variable: globalStorage

А в *Chrome*

> Uncaught ReferenceError: globalStorage is not defined

Comment: А в чем проблема увеличить время жизни сессии?

Comment: @Darth А как увеличить? Я вроде и сейчас не ставлю ограничений на это

Comment: можешь использовать jwt https://jwt.io/

Comment: @Erm значит у вас стоит дефолтное значение. Я давно уже не силен в php, так что лучше спросите [у гугла](http://loco.ru/materials/229-php-prolong-session-time) как.

Comment: @Darth, а разве сессии не удаляются после закрытия браузера?

Comment: @Erm это зависит от настроек. По сути, сессия - очень простой механизм. У клиента в том или ином виде хранится идентификатор (обычно это кука, но есть и другие способы, например передача в GET). Весь вопрос в том, как долго клиент будет хранить этот идентификатор, а сервер - соотвествующие ему данные. Оба этих параметра можно настроить. Вам нужно только узнать у гугла как это  делается в PHP, и вы сможете хранить сессию годами) пока клиент куки не почистит.

Comment: а использовать Cookie не модно уже?

Comment: @Manitikyl вроде бы PHP по умолчанию использует куку для хранения PHPSESSID. Просто по умолчанию у неё время жизни настроено так, что она живет, пока вы браузер не закроете